# Parsing Formatted Text and Keeping Only Relevant Data Using Python

Tags: python

I would like to read a text string and pull out information which appear in a certain format or manipulate them.

Case 1:

I have the following input string:

```
a='15mm' b='10mm' c='50mm' d='100mils'
```

I would like to search for substrings $value which appear in the format "b='$value'".

Case 2:

I have a list with almost identical string type members:

```
L=["a='15mm' b='10mm' c='50mm' d='100mils'",
   "a='15mm' b='11mm' c='50mm' d='100mils'",
   "a='15mm' b='10mm' c='50mm' d='40mils'"]
```

I want to reduce this list by discarding the segments of the for $p=$q which remain unchanged between the members. The simplified list should look like:

```
R=["b='10mm' d='100mils'",
   "b='11mm' d='100mils'",
   "b='10mm' d='40mils'"]
```

Comment: I read the question multiple times but I can't figure out what you are asking. Could you please rewrite the question in a clearer way?

Comment: For use case 1, that's exactly what regex are for, in python the module for it is called re. For your case 2, you probably need 2 iterations on your list : one for checking if each key has one or more values, the second to remove what you need. Anyway try to do it and ask a question if you're stuck, your question is too broad for now.

Comment: If this is the start of doing lots of operations with this information, maybe consider to convert the strings to dictionaries that are easier to work with: dict([x.split("=") for x in xx.split(" ")]) where xx is your input string.

Answer (score 0):

For case 1 you can just use the [split()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_split.htm) method.

```
str = "a='15mm' b='10mm' c='50mm' d='100mils'";
values = str.split("=");
```

This returns a list of lines where all the odd indices are your values e.g. "'10mm' " (notice the space, you can delete that with the following method)

And with the use of split() and [replace()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_replace.htm) you can also do case 2 (replace with and empty string).

Hope that gets you going :)

-G4A

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple solution using [`regex`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html):

```
import re
case1= "a='15mm' b='10mm' c='50mm' d='100mils'"
#Find all starting with 'b=' and then having one or more digit and ending with mm'
case1out = re.findall('b=\'\d{1,}mm\'',s)

case2 = ["a='15mm' b='10mm' c='50mm' d='100mils'","a='15mm' b='11mm' c='50mm' d='100mils'","a='15mm' b='10mm' c='50mm' d='40mils'"]

#Use list comprehension
case2out = [x.split(' ')[1::2]  for x in L]
```

And the results will be like this:

[image]

> **Updated answer using [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html)**

```
import re
import pandas as pd
import StringIO

data = """a='15mm' b='10mm' c='50mm' d='100mils'
a='15mm' b='11mm' c='50mm' d='100mils'
a='15mm' b='10mm' c='50mm' d='40mils'"""

#Lets get the data into a DataFrame
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO.StringIO(data),delim_whitespace=True,header=None,names=list('abcd'))
print df

#In the following line, first Transpose the data, then check if each row has the same value, it returns a DataFrame of booleans
dft = df.T.apply(lambda x: x == x[0], axis=1)

#Lets get the output, first transpose the data, then transpose dft, get the average of the booleans, 
#if the average is less than one then the values in that particular row are not same.
#Finally transpose to get desired output data
output = df.T[dft.T.mean() < 1].T

print output
```

And the results will look like this:

Initial data

[image: initial data]

Result Data

To save the result into a file `output.to_csv('output.csv',index=False)`

[image]

Comment: Case 1 is resolved. Now regarding Case 2, I do not know which variables change values from one line to the next, so I need to be able to find that out first before slicing as you suggest. Is there a way to go through all of the first elements of each line and determine if they are the same or not?

Comment: How does your data look like before coming into case2 variable? Or how does it look like before coming into python? Based on the way you have the data - we can chose a module on python to make the working easy.

Comment: Very much like the example of Case 2. Basically it is an internal variation array from within an engineering simulator called HFSS which uses Python as the scripting language. Generally each line corresponds to a design iterations. So there may be many lines (iterations) and many variables. I want to keep only the variables and values that change across the design iterations and delete the rest.

Comment: Ideally each column that is made up of identical entries of the form $Varable = $Value will be deleted.

Comment: OK there is a module called `pandas` which is very suitable for what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you, that helps a lot. But one problem remains: I do not know ahead of time what the "names" input is for df. In the example it was list("abcd"). In reality data = ["$h1='0' $h2='-4.5mil' ...], I do not know know what the variables are and how many. What we have is a blank-space delimited 2D array of data, where each design iteration is framed inside a double quotation similar to the original example.

Comment: This solution shall work even if you are not knowing the names of the columns, irrespective of number of columns.

Comment: Then I must be missing something because when I remove the "names" argument from pd. read_csv it does not rearrange the data in a table format.

Comment: Did you remove `headers=None` also? If not remove it.